# call component user define function in ag grid cellClick() event

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I have created

```
    this.xxxsetgridOptions = {
        rowSelection: 1,
        columnDefs: this.setvsp_param_columns,
        onCellClicked: function (params) {
            params.node.data["is_row_update"] = 1;
            this.setValidator();


        },
        getRowStyle:function(params){
            if(params.data.is_new_rec==1) {
                return {'background-color': 'rgb(192,192,192)'}
             }
        },
        suppressScrollOnNewData:true,
        rowHeight:28,                      
    };
```

this is **this.setValidator();** component's function.
so  i want to call this function when ag grid cell clicked?
how to call this in angular 2?

Comment: Can you put your code in plunker? if its a scope issue then you can declare self=this; and use self.setvalidator();

Comment: onCellClicked: function (params) {
                           self=this;
                            params.node.data["is_row_update"] = 1;
                            seld.setValidator();
                
                
                        },not working

Comment: you need to declare self=this before you set the grid options. Before the function this.xxxsetgridOptions = {}

Comment: does the below answer solve your problem? If so could you please accept it so other users having the same question can be benefited?

Answer (score 2):

```
self=this;

this.xxxsetgridOptions = {
        rowSelection: 1,
        columnDefs: this.setvsp_param_columns,
        onCellClicked: function (params) {
            params.node.data["is_row_update"] = 1;
            self.setValidator();


        },
        getRowStyle:function(params){
            if(params.data.is_new_rec==1) {
                return {'background-color': 'rgb(192,192,192)'}
             }
        },
        suppressScrollOnNewData:true,
        rowHeight:28,                      
    };
```